# Connecting altium busses with different width

Tags: altium, bus

I have 3 busses in the project:

- `ADC[16..1]`,
- `BUSA[8..1]`,
- `BUSB[8..1]`,

I would like to connect `ADC[8..1]` to `BUSA[8..1]` and `ADC[16..9]` to `BUSB[8..1]`. Is this possible without adding any series resistors? Whats the cleanest way to accomplish this?

I would really like to avoid dividing the `ADC` bus on 2 parts, i.e. `ADCA[8..1]` and `ADCB[8..1]`...

Comment: This is kind of confusing, you want to have 2 differently named signals (like ADC1 and BUSA1) connect to each other without changing the name? You could use a 0R link (a bridge)...

Comment: I'm not sure about Altium, but in Eagle you can create another bus, ie `ADC[1..8]` which contains just the signals 1..8 of `ADC[1..16]`. The bus is just a shortcut for naming a lot of nets.

Comment: I would just use an array of net ties if you must construct your schematic this way. you might want to try re-configuring your schematic to use named harnesses.

Comment: Yes, a net tie might be the solution. Thanks.